# CKEditor cross domain requests on file upload

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, cross-domain

I have latest version of ckeditor. I did file upload to my remote service. that service after uploading, returns uploaded file link. that is included as iframe 'upload' tab.

So that is all ok. But when I try to switch tab or close image uploader popup window 'ckeditor' throws error:

"Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3101" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:61666". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Is where any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is a security standard. Browser auto check and prevent it like default way. Have no method to pass it.

But in your case I have a trick to resolve this problem, you can try this:

- After click "send it to server" and receive a response.
- Detect your iframe source by id in DOM
- Change the iframe's source domain to current domain. (important thing of this trick to pass error "Blocked a frame with origin..." )
- And do continue like as you did.